# Expose API over TCP of snap-installed Docker on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, and this server has Docker installed, and it was installed using snap.

Now i need to expose the Docker API over TCP, but because it was installed using snap, none of the settings I changed, or tutorials i followed did anything.

I've searched all around but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working finally.

By running: `systemctl status snap.docker.dockerd.service` I was able to see which was the loaded service file: `/etc/systemd/system/snap.docker.dockerd.service`

Just looked inside this file looking for the `ExecStart` directive. It was there.

So just had to add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to that line, so it ended up looking like:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run docker.dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`

Rebooted. Works.

Comment: I'm looking for the same issue. The problem I have with your (working) solution is that you modify a package-controlled file. There is supposed to be a way to achieve that by adding the system-specific modifications in a file external to the package.